# Add dropdown menu in a view's ToolBarManager

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to add several dynamically created actions to a view. This works to add them to the View Menu in the top right corner:

```
private void fillActionBars() {
  IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
  IMenuManager manager = bars.getMenuManager();
  IMenuManager myMenu = new MenuManager("Menu title", MY_MENU_ID);
  // add actions to myMenu
  manager.add(myMenu);
  bars.updateActionBars();
}
```

This works fine. However, I want to add the actions to a dropdown menu in the toolbar instead (so the user can see them immediately). If I replace the third line with

```
IToolbarManager manager = bars.getToolBarManager();
```

the menu doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, this doesn't work. A workaround that works fine, not using a MenuManager but a drop down action and a menu creator:

```
IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
IToolbarManager manager = bars.getToolBarManager();
Action act=new Action("Menu title",SWT.DROP_DOWN){};
act.setMenuCreator(new MyMenuCreator());
manager.add(act);

class MyMenuCreator implements IMenuCreator{
    public Menu getMenu(Control ctrl){
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IToolbarManager.add(IContributionItem)` with a class that implements `IContributionItem`. See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.FastViewBarContextMenuContribution` as an example.

Comment: The problem is, this is what I do in the question: `IMenuManager` does implement `IContributionItem`. So obviously there are some extra requirements.